# Resharper Annotations on a delegate method?

Tags: delegates, annotations, resharper

I'm trying to create the External Annotations file for Commons.Logging. It's practically a straight copy from the log4net configuration, but what gets me puzzled is how can I decorate the following code with proper [`StringFormatMethodAttribute`](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__String_Formatting_Methods.html):

```cs
public interface ILog
{
  void Error(Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback);
}

public delegate string FormatMessageHandler(string format, params object[] args);

// usage
log.Error(m => m(
  "my expensive to calculate argument is: {0}",
    CalculateMessageInfo()) );
```

The attribute is only valid on constructors and methods, is there a way to coerce it onto this use case?